# Is handling or raising Python exceptions efficient?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

Lately I've been using some large dictionaries (large meaning ~thousands of elements) and so I have been employing this little guy:

```
try:
    dict[key]
    #do something
except KeyError:
    pass
```

In place of

```
if key in dict.keys()
    #do something
```

I want to know *at which dictionary size* the former becomes more efficient than the latter? From my understanding the second method is faster if `keys()` is small, but at what point does it start becoming better to use the first method?

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
if key in dict.keys():
```

Python 2.x has to do O(N) comparisons to find if `key` is in the `dict` or not, because `dict.keys()` returns a list of keys. (But that is fine in Python 3.x, since it returns a set-like view object, lookup will be faster)

Instead, make use of the constant time lookup like this

```
if key in dict:
```

This will compute the hash of the `key` and look for that in `dict`.

Comment: Or, my personal favourite: a = dict.get(key, None)

Comment: @fileoffset True, if you want avoid the exception and to get the default value, you can do that. But OP is trying to do key lookup, so I would settle with `in` method :-)

Comment: I agree - although you can do an: `if a:` to emulate that as well :)